# Running my Macro through all Worksheets in a Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

currently I have a macro that runs and finds headers "DATE" and "DT" in the Active Worksheet and reformats the cells in the column. I'm hoping to make it run through all Worksheets and run the macro. Here's the current VBA code:

```
Sub DateFormatting()
    Dim x As Variant
    With ActiveWorksheet
        For Each x In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
            If InStr(1, Replace(x.Value, "DATE", "DT", , , vbTextCompare), "DT", vbTextCompare) Then
                Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(2), x.EntireColumn).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm"
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `for each ws in thisworkbook.worksheets`?

Comment: Yes. Ideally it will run this in all of the worksheets in the workbook.

Comment: He was giving you the answer.  Put another loop on the outside of your existing using what he typed.

Comment: Also need to change `With ActiveSheet` to `With ws` if using @findwindow suggestion. Otherwise, it will always affect whatever sheet that was active when the macro was run.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman the original had `with ws` instead.

Comment: I get an error that says "Method or data member not found," any ideas?

Comment: Sub DateFormatting2()
    Dim x As Variant
    With ws
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheet
            For Each x In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
                If InStr(1, Replace(x.Value, "DATE", "DT", , , vbTextCompare), "DT", vbTextCompare) Then
                    Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(2), x.EntireColumn).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm"
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Comment: Your With should be inside the first loop not outside.

Comment: Like this? This doesn't seem to work either: 

Sub DateFormatting2()
    Dim x As Variant
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheet
        With ws
            For Each x In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
                If InStr(1, Replace(x.Value, "DATE", "DT", , , vbTextCompare), "DT", vbTextCompare) Then
                    Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(2), x.EntireColumn).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm"
                End If
            Next
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Comment: Also this line `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheet` needs an `s` on the end. `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to summarize all comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DateFormatting2()

Dim x As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        For Each x In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
            If InStr(1, Replace(x.Value2, "DATE", "DT", , , vbTextCompare), "DT", vbTextCompare) Then
                Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(2), x.EntireColumn).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm"
            End If
        Next x
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comments:

1. You missed the `s` at the end of `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheet`
2. You had the `for each ws` loop inside the `with ws` statement while it should be the other way around. You cannot use `ws` if it isn't initiated yet.
3. To end a `With` you need to `End With` and not `Next`
4. `Option Explicit` just for good measures.